# Can I pass arguments to the compare subroutine of sort in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, compare

I'm using `sort` with a customized comparison subroutine I've written:

```
sub special_compare {
 # calc something using $a and $b
 # return value
}

my @sorted = sort special_compare @list;
```

I know it's best use `$a` and `$b` which are automatically set, but sometimes I'd like my `special_compare` to get more arguments, i.e.:

```
sub special_compare {
 my ($a, $b, @more) = @_; # or maybe 'my @more = @_;' ?
 # calc something using $a, $b and @more
 # return value
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `sort BLOCK LIST` syntax, see [perldoc -f sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

If you have written the above `special_compare` sub, you can do, for instance:

```
my @sorted = sort { special_compare($a, $b, @more) } @list;
```

Comment: You may want to pass a reference to `@more` to stop it being copied all the time.

Comment: Or just use in-line code instead of calling a sub, if appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use closure in place of the sort subroutine:

```
my @more;
my $sub = sub {        
    # calc something using $a, $b and @more
};

my @sorted = sort $sub @list;
```

If you want to pass the elements to be compared in `@_`, set subroutine's prototype to `($$)`. Note: this is slower than unprototyped subroutine.

Comment: mscha's solution is cleaner and seems to work. Do you see any reason not using it?

Comment: @David: using closure may be more efficient. I didn't run benchmark though.

Comment: If performance is a consideration and the comparison function is heavy, have a look at the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that $a and $b do not loose their special property of not being copied. @mscha's solution copies its arguments into the subroutine (I think...), while this solution doesn't.

Comment: And I thought Schwartzian transform was yet another obscure reference to a quote from Arnold Schwarzenegger ... But thanks for the info!