# custom sort method for hashes which will automatically use the approporiate hash

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

My hash contains binary numbers as keys:

```
my %h = ("1010" => 1, "1110" => 0, "0001" => 3, "1100" => 2);
```

In perl I can use custom function for sorting hash. This is my function for sorting binary numbers from lowest to largest:

```
sub sort_binary_numbers {
  my $a_dec = oct("0b".$a);
  my $b_dec = oct("0b".$b);
  return $a_dec <=> $b_dec;
}
```

I can sort hash using this function following way:

```
print Dumper sort sort_binary_numbers keys %h;
```

And the result will be:

```
$VAR1 = '0001';
$VAR2 = '1010';
$VAR3 = '1100';
$VAR4 = '1110';
```

I want to sort hash using values not keys. I can do following:

```
print Dumper sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h;
```

As you can see I have to use hash name in sorting block. The problem is how to rewrite this sorting block to function (as above examples) and automatically get the appropriate hash name in function. I've tried access hash name using `@_` but it was not printed e.g.

```
sub sort_by_value {
  print Dumper @_; # This was not printed
  print ref @_;    # This was not printed
  return $b <=> $a;
}
```

And call it following way:

```
print Dumper sort sort_by_value keys %h;
```

The interesting part is that when I wrap this sorting in to another function and call it in loop from this function I will get the output of data dumper that was previously missing (but I still did not get the output of ref command):

```
sub calling_from_function {
  my %h = %{$_[0]};
  foreach my $key (sort sort_by_value keys %h){
  }
}

&calling_from_function(\%h);
```

Then I get this output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '0001' => 3,
          '1010' => 1,
          '1110' => 0,
          '1100' => 2
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '0001' => 3,
          '1010' => 1,
          '1110' => 0,
          '1100' => 2
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '0001' => 3,
          '1010' => 1,
          '1110' => 0,
          '1100' => 2
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '0001' => 3,
          '1010' => 1,
          '1110' => 0,
          '1100' => 2
        };
```

Questions:

1. How can I replace sorting block in this command `print Dumper sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h;` with function and get the appropriate name of hash inside sortign function?
2. Why wrapping from another function works?
3. Why `ref` does not works?

Comment: See [Can I pass arguments to the compare subroutine of sort in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3995537/176646)

Comment: Also note that if you're just trying to sort `Data::Dumper` output, you can use `$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys`: "Can also be set to a subroutine reference which will be called for each hash that is dumped. In this case `Data::Dumper` will call the subroutine once for each hash, passing it the reference of the hash. The purpose of the subroutine is to return a reference to an array of the keys that will be dumped, in the order that they should be dumped."

Comment: by the way, `sort sort_binary_numbers keys %h;` can be shortened to `sort keys %h;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sorting subroutine doesn't take parameters normally (i.e. unless prototypes are involved) through `@_`, but through `$a` and `$b`. `ref @array` can never return anything, as an array is never a reference.

Wrapping by another function works, because you populate `@_` by parameters to the wrapper.

Use a wrapper to sort any hash:

```
sub sort_by_value {
    my %h = @_;
    return sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h
}

print Dumper(sort_by_value(%h));
```

You can also send the hash reference to the subroutine:

```
sub sort_by_value {
    my ($h) = @_;
    return sort { $h->{$b} <=> $h->{$a} } keys %$h
}

print Dumper sort_by_value(\%h);
```

Answer (score 3):

So you want to have a generic sorting function such as

```
my $sorter = sub { $_[0]{$b} <=> $_[0]{$a} };
```

When it comes time to sort, just use

```
my @sorted_keys = sort { $sorter->(\%h) } keys(%h);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use hash as a list, convert it to k/v aref pairs, perform sort on values (second element), and pick keys from sorted list (roughly it is Schwartzian transform in disguise).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'pairs';

my %h = ("1010" => 1, "1110" => 0, "0001" => 3, "1100" => 2);
my @k = map $_->[0],
   sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
   pairs %h;
```

without additional modules,

```
my @k = map $_->[0],
   sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
   map [ $_, $h{$_} ],
   keys %h;
```